# Quando troco o valor de um ComboBox todos mudam

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Tenho um banco de dados com duas tabelas, Tab1 e Tab2. 
Na Tab 1 eu tenho Cd_Tab1 e Nm_Objeto.
Na Tab2 eu tenho Cd_Tab2, Cd_Tab1.
As duas estão relacionadas.
No meu projeto tenho 4 ComboBox, todas devem representar o valor de Cd_Tab2, mas cada uma irá gravar um novo Cd_Tab2(Ex: Primeira Cmb = Cd_Tab2(1), Segunda Cmb = Cd_Tab2(2) etc...
O problema que estou tendo é que quando eu mudo o valor de uma cmb no projeto todas as outras mudam junto.

Codigo XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="btCmbAtkBaAtr2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,79,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberPath="Nm_Objeto" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tab1ViewSource}}" 
            SelectedValuePath="Cd_Tab1" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Cd_Tab1, Source={StaticResource Tab2ViewSource}}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="btCmbAtkBaAtr2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberPath="Nm_Atr" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource atributosNormaisViewSource}}" SelectedValuePath="Cd_AtributosNormais" SelectedValue="{Binding Cd_AtributosNormais, Source={StaticResource ataquesBasicosViewSource}}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="btCmbAtkBaAtr3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberPath="Nm_Atr" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource atributosNormaisViewSource}}" SelectedValuePath="Cd_AtributosNormais" SelectedValue="{Binding Cd_AtributosNormais, Source={StaticResource ataquesBasicosViewSource}}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="btCmbAtkBaAtr4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberPath="Nm_Atr" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource atributosNormaisViewSource}}" SelectedValuePath="Cd_AtributosNormais" SelectedValue="{Binding Cd_AtributosNormais, Source={StaticResource ataquesBasicosViewSource}}"/>
```

Tab1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tab2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fala em 4 *ComboBox* mas só postou o código de uma.

Comment: Todas as outras possuem o mesmo código, o que muda é o nome delas. Obrigado por corrigir o código

Comment: Se o código referente ao *binding* é igual em todas, como o *binding mode* por defeito é *Mode=TwoWay*, ao alterar o valor numa ele é alterado nas restantes.

Comment: E como eu poderia resolver isso? Trocando o mode do binding?

Comment: Eu estava pensando se o problema não estava no banco de dados, na tabela 1 no caso, pois ele só vai cria uma nova row se eu der o comando INSERT, certo?

Comment: Trocar o modo de *binding* não resolverá. Como não faço ideia do que você pretende não será fácil ajudar. Julgo no entanto que, como cada "ComboBox" se refere a dados diferentes, também cada *binding* tem de se referir a coisas diferentes.

Comment: Vou tentar colocar imagens das tabelas para melhor compreensão e colocar os códigos das 4 cmb's

Comment: Você quer criar ao mesmo tempo 4 registos diferentes na Tab2?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Julgo que então terá de ter um `ataquesBasicosViewSource` diferente para cada combobox.

Comment: entendi...achei que daria para criar 4 registros na mesma tabela automaticamente. Obrigado pela ajuda